# What does var n = (t.currentDevicePixelRatio = e || ("undefined" != typeof window && window.devicePixelRatio) || 1); mean?

Tags: javascript

```
var n = (t.currentDevicePixelRatio = e || ("undefined" != typeof window && window.devicePixelRatio) || 1);
```

Can someone tell me what this means? I know "||" means "OR", and I know that an expression like

```
n = n || {}
```

is setting the value of n to an empty object if n is a falsy value. But what happens what you have an equals sign in there? And the second component is even more weird to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add some whitespace to make it more readable:

```
    var n = (
        t.currentDevicePixelRatio = e
        ||
        (
            "undefined" != typeof window
            &&
            window.devicePixelRatio
        )
        ||
        1
    );
```

JavaScript expressions are evaluated left-to-right, parentheses-first. So the evaluation order is:

1. Copy the value of `e` into `t.currentDevicePixelRatio`.
2. The value of `e` is then emitted by the assignment `=` statement.
3. If *that value* is falsy, then evaluate the right-hand-side of the `||`:
4. So if `e` is not null (or undefined or an empty string) then that's that and the value of `e` is also assigned to `n` and the expression completes.
5. Otherwise, if `window` is defined (i.e. this script is running in a web-browser, as opposed to Node.js) then copy the value of `window.devicePixelRatio` into `t.currentDevicePixelRatio` and also into `n`.
6. If `window.devicePixelRatio` is undefined then use `1` for both `t.currentDevicePixelRatio` and `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the individual steps break down to:

```js
var n;

if (e) {
    t.currentDevicePixelRatio = e;
    n = t.currentDevicePixelRatio;
} else if ("undefined" != typeof window && window.devicePixelRatio) {
    t.currentDevicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
    n = t.currentDevicePixelRatio;
} else {
    t.currentDevicePixelRatio = 1;
    n = t.currentDevicePixelRatio;
}
```